# Voice Recognition in India for Android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am trying to develop an app that would have a module based on VR. I am from India. The words recognized or shown correctly by Google Search on Android powered LG Optimus device is something more of the American accent. Is there any way for it to recognize accent other than that of America? And yes does the VR engine work here in India...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is to use Pocketsphinx speech recognition engine

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

Being open source this engine is highly configurable and can be adapted to your needs. For example it's possible to adapt English models to recognize Indian english with a very high accuracy. For more details see

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt

The model for Indian English is available in CMUSphinx downloads

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Indian%20English/

However, these days at 2019 I recommend you to use Kaldi, it is much more accurate. See https://github.com/alphacep/kaldi-android-demo

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, will look into the options

Comment: @Nikolay Last link is not valid. Could you please provide the correct one?